# Render Android WebBrowser App with Delphi XE7

Tags: android, delphi, twebbrowser, delphi-xe7

I'm developing an Android App with Delphi Xe7. App has a `TWebBrowser` which loads a normal internet web page like www.lfp.com. The problem I have is that the web page displayed doesn't adjust itself to the `TWebBrowser`, you have to scroll the page. I would like to show the entire web page, and after that zoom where I like.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Most web pages do not adjust themselves to the web browser window size in any way, at least in my web browsers the scrollbars appear and I have to scroll to other parts of the page.

Comment: Ok, the thing is that i can do a zoom out and adjust the web page. I don't know if it will be possible to do an automatic zoom when the page is displayed.